# Protect HTML form from Javascript/Attacks

Tags: php, html, css, whitelist

I have a form and as of right now, you can type any javascript, etc. you want. Any XSS, etc.

How do I go about creating a whitelist so you can only post characters.

At some point I would like anything that starts with `http://` to be converted to

`<a href="http://..."></a>`

Thanks

Is this efficient?
http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: you know you can't use client side code for data validation - your users can just turn off JS. So unless you are running server-side javascript, you are going to have to check server-side in another language for the presence of script tags/bad characters...

Comment: Thanks, I realize that now. Can you recommend any prebuilt solutions?

Comment: what is the server side script you are using? is it php, .net. perl, ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> jQuery or Javascript is preferred

Well, no, you can't do that, you see? Because even if you 'sanitize' your data using javascript, noone's stopping anyone from

- turning off javascript
- using a browser's developer console to mess with the data
- doing the POST directly, without a browser

In other words, you have to perform the validation/sanitization on the server side. Javascript validation is there to enhance the experience of your users (by providing instant feedback on invalid input, for example).

Comment: I get it. So do what do you recommend using then? Thanks

Comment: ??? @Switz, shylent did recomend something: `(...) you have to perform the validation/sanitization on the server side.`

Answer (score 1):

But still, in many high-load applications developers use *partially* client-side verifications (but all inputs have to be prepared for writing to db).

As you will be using PHP, i suggest you to parse your $_POST values with htmlspecialchars(), mysql_real_escape_string() and so on.

You will have to use regular expression to convert anything that starts with "http://" to links (well, you can also use explode('.', $_POST['yourInput']) which can be easier for you).

Comment: Very useful thank you :) To update your post: mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php